# TD not stacking responsive with Outlook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML email with standard TD's side by side. However, on mobile I want these to stack. I have used display:block; that works on some email browsers, however on others (Outlook) this does not work.

HTML is as follows:-

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
  .res-block td {display: block !important;}
}
```

```html
<table class="main" width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: #fff;margin:auto !important">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="res-block">
      <td style="background: #ff9400;">hello</td>
      <td style="background: #ff9400;">john</td>    
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
```

Can someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Are media queries supported by the version of Outlook that you are testing? https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/

Answer (score 0):

try to use `box-sizing:border-box` with `clear:both`
**check the snippet:**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
  td {
    display:block; 
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    clear:both;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="main" width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: #fff;margin:auto !important">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="res-block">
      <td style="background: #ff9400;">hello</td>
      <td style="background: #ff9400;">john</td>    
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Simply change the td to th, then this stacks correctly on Outlook mobile.

Great hack if anyone is looking for it!